# palindrome.cpp:9:26: error: 'size' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, string, scope, size, palindrome

i have written a code to check palindrome but it gives error on command prompt and on a online compiler but i executed the code on a different online compiler where it compiled successfully and gives the desirable result.
the error is: **palindrome.cpp:9:26: error: 'size' was not declared in this scope**

````
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string num_str = "";
    cin >> num_str;
    string new_str = "";

    for(int x = (size(num_str)-1); x >= 0; x--){
        new_str += num_str[x];
    }

    cout << (num_str == new_str ? "palindrome" : "Non-palindrome");

    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: `size` is not declared. What do you expect from `size(num_str)` ? Did you mean `num_str.size()` ?

Comment: Missing `#include <string>`

Answer (score 1):

First, a standard header may include other standard headers, and it's not really defined which, so using `std::string` might work on some compilers without including `<string>`, but on others not. And technically, `std::size` is defined in `<iterator>`, although `<string>` is guaranteed to include it. (I still think it better to be explicit and include `<iterator>` anyway, but this is largely a matter of preference.)

Once you've included the necessary headers, you can use either `num_str.size()` (member function of `std::string`) or `std::size( num_str )` (free function defined in `<iterator>`). Note too that the free function is a relatively recent addition to the standard, and might not be available on all compilers.

Answer (score 0):

To get the size of a string, you use a member function. Change this line:

```
for(int x = (size(num_str)-1); ... )
```

to

```
for(int x = num_str.size()-1; ... )
```

Additionally, you should probably include :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
// ...
```

Comment: It's worked fine without  adding ```# include <string>```.

Comment: That is probably because iostream includes string. However, since this is different from compiler to compiler, it is best practice to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

The `std::size()` function is only available in C++17 or later. Check your compiler standard.

Comment: Even with C++17, the code would need to include one of the required headers; the `<iostream>` header is not *required* to define it.

Answer (score 0):

use std::string::length() instead.
num_str.length()-1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).